# Low signal strength

Tags: 8.0, signal

I am using Lumia 620 with Vodafone as carrier. Last week it's display unit got replaced. After that I'm experiencing a problem. I don't know whether it has any relationship with display unit change. Phone's signal strength got very low, sometimes empty. And calls got dropped because of this. I tested the SIM with another phone but can't find any problem with it. Contacted the operator, they replied their network works fine.

Is there anyone experienced same or got any solutions?

Comment: Was the repair done by a Nokia authorised repair centre?

Comment: Yes, it's. At Nokia Care in my city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that the repair has some form of warranty with it, I'd be inclined to take it back to the Nokia Repair centre, and explain that there has been degradation in signal reception *since they repaired the screen*. At the very least, I would expect them to be able to do some diagnostics to determine if the antennae is operating within specification.